# Как из класса в котором реализован меню, вызвать метод родителя

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Добрый день.

У меня есть два класс, один из которых реализовывает кастомный адаптер, и в нем же я реализовал меню со списком.

```
public class RVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;

    public static class Person {
        private final String title;
        private  final String descriptions;
        private final int Ids;

        public Person(String title, String descriptions, int Ids) {
            this.title = title;
            this.descriptions = descriptions;
            this.Ids = Ids;
        }
    }

    public class PersonViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        CardView cv;
        TextView personTitle;
        TextView personText;
        TextView txtOptionDigit;

        PersonViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            cv = (CardView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.cv);
            personTitle = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_name);
            personText = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.person_text);
            txtOptionDigit = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtOptionDigit);

        }
    }

    private  int id;
    List<Person> persons;

    public RVAdapter(List<Person> persons, Context context){
        this.persons = persons;
        this.mContext = context;
    }



    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final PersonViewHolder personViewHolder, final int i) {
        final PlayersVideoYouTube pvy = new PlayersVideoYouTube();
        personViewHolder.personTitle.setText(persons.get(i).title);
        personViewHolder.personText.setText(persons.get(i).descriptions);
    // personViewHolder.txtOptionDigit.setImageResource(persons.get(i).photoId);
        personViewHolder.personTitle.setId(i);
        personViewHolder.personTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d("LOG", "Был нажат "  + v.getId());
                id = v.getId();

                PopupMenu popupMenu = new PopupMenu(mContext, personViewHolder.txtOptionDigit);
                popupMenu.inflate(R.menu.game_menu);
                popupMenu.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

                        switch (item.getItemId()) {
                            case R.id.delete:
                                //Delete item
                                persons.remove(i);
                                notifyDataSetChanged();
                                Toast.makeText(mContext,"Запись была временно удалена!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case R.id.cadre:
                                //Delete item
                                persons.remove(i);
                                break;
                            default:
                                break;
                        }
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popupMenu.show();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return persons.size();
    }
}
```

Этот кастомный адаптер с меню отображается в классе PlayersVideoYouTube введи списка RelativeLayout.

Как теперь из этого меню мне вызвать методы класса PlayersVideoYouTube ?
Сейчас при вызове метода из меню, код не работает,только LOG.d выводиться в консоль.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
 ((PlayersVideoYouTube)mContext).yourDesiredMethod();
```

Если вам нужно использовать этот же адаптер для нескольких операций, выполните следующие действия:

Создайте интерфейс:

```
public interface MyInterface{
public void foo();
}
```

Реализуйте в активити:

```
public class PlayersVideoYouTube extends Activity implements MyInterface{
public void foo(){
    //do stuff
}
```

Затем передайте  в Adapter:

```
public class RVAdapter extends 
         RecyclerView.Adapter<RVAdapter.PersonViewHolder> {


private MyInterface listener;

public RVAdapter(MyInterface listener,....//){

this.listener = listener;

}
```

И где-нибудь в адаптере, когда вам нужно вызвать этот метод Activity:

```
listener.foo();
```

Comment: Спасибо за столь развернутый ответ, оба способа мне помогли. Ранее я уже пробовал через интерфейс запустить код, но у меня так и не получилось. Теперь буду знать как еще можно использовать интерфейсы.

Comment: Рад был помочь!